# Sign in at invocation for Cortana not working.

Tags: cortana-skills-kit

We have a Cortana Skill that we had connected to bot in dev.botframework.com. We also had configured authentication for Azure active directory v1. so that when skill is invoked for the first time a user will be authenticated by our corp AD. Here is the documentation link we followed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/configure-connected-account

With the recent changes we need to manager Cortana settings on my.knowledge.store. So I did migrated by Cortana skill over these and now it shows as a BOTLET. I see my auth settings are showing up now under Authentication  > Configs in Vault >. When I open auth setting I don't see an option called 'Sign in at invocation'

Was it removed ? Now my skill no more asks for sign in card.

ref: 
https://help.knowledge.store/tutorials_code_samples/bot_framework/index.html#
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nNsN.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details? What backend are you using. Is it a c# botframework skill?

Comment: Can you please confirm that the auth setting in Vault are correct?

Comment: Looks like there is a know bug in Cortana Knowledge store know Microsoft is working on fixing. Once it is fixed it should work.